# Ruby: window print screen win32API call

Tags: ruby

When you press alt+printscreen (in windows at least) you get a screenshot of the current active (and visible?) window.

How can I call this using win32Api calls?

Answer (score 0):

How about `Win32::Screenshot`?
https://github.com/jarmo/win32screenshot

```
gem install win32screenshot
```

```
require 'win32/screenshot'

# Take a screenshot of the foreground
Win32::Screenshot::Take.of(:foreground).write("image.png")

# Take a screenshot of the window with the specified title
Win32::Screenshot::Take.of(:window, :title => "Abc").write("image.bmp")
```

Comment: Hmm, I would prefer a win32API call if possible.